# iOS & Google APIs REST 

Tags: ios, api, rest, google-api, restful-authentication

I'm trying to connect to Google RESTful API's but all I get went doing so is a login screen.

My goal is to be able to create a Calendar in Google Calendars using RESTful.

**I already created my API keys on Google APIs Console.**

I did this:

```
NSString* baseURL = @"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?";
NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",baseURL,[self dictionaryToURLStringVariables:[self authParameters]]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
NSURLConnection *connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Auth parameters

```
-(NSDictionary*)authParameters
{
    NSDictionary* dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"code",@"response_type", redirectURI,@"redirect_uri", API_ID,@"client_id", @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",@"scope", nil];
    return dictionary;
}
```

The response is working fine but all I get is a Google HTML login.

I checked out and google has it's own Objective-C library which is far too complicated from my point of view and is not based on iDevices but Desktop.

**My 1st question is:**

Is there a SIMPLE way to do it all via REST ( login, token, CRUD... ) just sending and posting requests?

e.g: http://www.googleapis.com/login?user=MY_EMAIL&password=MY_PASSWORD (<- of course not than simple / insecure but you get the idea...)

Comment: Please limit each post to a single question.

Comment: I deleted the second one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For question 1, try implementing this NSURLConnection delegate method.  It allows you to supply credentials when the service asks for them.

```
 - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
```